# Firebase onMessageReceived() is not being called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase Push notifications in my Android application. I have followed the Firebase documentation accordingly, Everything works fine, `onRefreshToken()` is also being called but when I try to send a notification using Firebase console. It shows completed but I can't see any logs in my Android Studio. I am sure that 'onMessageReceived' is not being called.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="app.user.oshyerllc">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="replace">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBf-y05iET2_UyoWTZnKmdjyZXGQKzVCp8" />

    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.OTPVerificationActivity" />
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.CreateProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.CreateProfileSocialActivity" />
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.SocialOTPVerificationAcitvity" />
    <activity android:name="app.user.oshyerllc.MapActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />

    <service android:name=".OshyerMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service android:name=".OshyerInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


</application>
```

**OshyerMessagingService.java (inside main package)**

```
package app.user.oshyerllc;


import android.util.Log;   
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class OshyerMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "OshyerMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            Log.d(TAG,"message recieved");

    }
}
```

**OshyerInstanceIDService.java:**

```
package app.user.oshyerllc;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class OshyerInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "OshyerInstanceIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

It's not throwing me any errors. Also I have gone through most of the questions related to the above issue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Quoting docs `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

1.Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
2.Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity. Does this happen in your case?

Comment: My app is in foreground but still onMessageRecieved is not being called

Comment: is the google-services.json file included with proper setup?

Comment: it's inside app/ and I set it up using firebase assistnt

Comment: There were several mentions in the text of `onMessageRecieved`, which is a misspelling. However, it appears correctly in your code, so I have corrected the mispelled copies.

Answer (score 0):

> onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> 1. Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>      device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app
>      launcher by default.
> 2. Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>      device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

your notification is sent to the system tray. and the `onMessageReceived` method is called only when your application is foreground

Comment: My app is in foreground but still onMessageRecieved is not being called

Comment: send it without data

Comment: All I am filling firebase console is Message Title and optional nothing else

Comment: it can be caused by phone manager check your phone setting, i was having the same problem and it was asus phone manager blocking the notification